# Disable Hyper-V prompt "Do you want to revert to the previous automatic checkpoint"

Tags: hyper-v

Every time I start my Hyper-V session I am prompted "Do you want to revert to the previous automatic checkpoint...Revert, Continue, Cancel"  I want to keep Automatic checkpoints turned on, but I don't want to be prompted each time I start the virtual machine if I want to revert.

Is there a setting to remove this prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Settings" on the affected VM, then look under Management > Checkpoints > `Use automatic checkpoints`

[image]

Comment: It is worth to note that after you disable the automatic checkpoint creation, you will get prompted one last time upon your next boot.

Comment: This answer does not meet the requested constraint: "I want to keep Automatic checkpoints turned on, but I don't want to be prompted each time I start the virtual machine if I want to revert."